# Flutter Permission Denial: opening provider org.chromium.chrome.browser.util.ChromeFileProvider

Tags: flutter, dart

The problem is when I go to the page with textfield it will produce this

```
W/PlatformPlugin(20347): Attempted to get clipboard data that requires additional permission(s).
W/PlatformPlugin(20347): See the exception details for which permission(s) are required, and consider adding them to your Android Manifest as described in:
W/PlatformPlugin(20347): https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview
W/PlatformPlugin(20347): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider org.chromium.chrome.browser.util.ChromeFileProvider from ProcessRecord
```

```
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2087)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2055)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2003)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProvider(IActivityManager.java:5411)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:6965)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2848)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:2258)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1690)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1644)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin.getClipboardData(PlatformPlugin.java:295)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin.access$700(PlatformPlugin.java:26)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin$1.getClipboardData(PlatformPlugin.java:85)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformChannel.java:141)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:182)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7804)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:984)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899): Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProviderImpl(ActivityManagerService.java:7567)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerService.java:8052)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:2231)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3029)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):    at com.android.server.am.OppoActivityManagerService.onTransact(OppoActivityManagerService.java:99)
W/PlatformPlugin(18899):
```

When I removed the textfield the problem gone. I've no idea what's the problem here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See this Flutter issue report:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65388

I don't really know what the details are but I do know that I had copied an image recently so it was in my "clipboard" in android 10.  I just copied some random text after highlighting it and this issue disappeared instantly.